# python dict get method runs the second argument even when key is in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

according to the doc, the get method of a dict can have two argument: key and a value to return if that key is not in the dict. However, when the second argument is a function, it'll run regardless of whether the key is in the dict or not:

```py
def foo():
    print('foo')

params={'a':1}
print(params.get('a', foo()))
# foo
# 1
```

As shown above, the key `a` is in the dict, but `foo()` still runs. What happens here?

Comment: You call the function _before_ calling the get method, to get the _value_ to pass as a parameter. [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) doesn't call a function if it's passed as a default anyway, you'd just get the function itself back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common misconception, the arguments must be evaluated whether or not they are used by the function, for example:

```
>>> def f(x, y, z): pass
... 
>>> f(print(1), print(2), print(3))
1
2
3
```

So the `print(1), print(2), print(3)` statements are executed even if the function `f` does not use the arguments. You can use `try` `except` instead to evaluate `foo()` only when it is needed:

```
try:
    x = params['a']
except KeyError:
    x = foo()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
params.get('a', foo())
```

Your second argument is **not** a function, it's a function **call**. So the `.get()` method calls it to obtain its second argument.

To put your function as a second argument, you have to remove parenthesis after it:

```
params.get('a', foo)
```

Comment: No, the `get()` method doesn't call it. It's called before `get()` is called. And removing the parentheses won't help since then we'd get the function as default value, instead of the return value of the function.

Comment: @mkrieger1, IMHO it's only an academic detail —the method `.get()`, seeing that its argument is not evaluated, **caused** its evaluation.

Comment: @mkrieger1 - it's not my proposed solution, it's **your** understanding of my answer. The second form I wrote only to show the difference between using a *function call* and a *function itself*.